# how to show data to the listview jquery mobile from mysql?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, mobile

i'm very beginner to android programming. and i have some problem that makes me feel confused.

my problem is i want to show list of data on the listview from a table of mysql database.
i've been trying to follow this tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/ and modified to suitable with my program. but my code didn't show the data from my database.

please help me. thanks

this is some of my code
this is my html code

```
<ol id="top10list" data-role="listview" data-theme="a"> </ol>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sql = "select m.namamovie, m.description from top10 t left outer join movie m on t.idmovie = m.idmovie";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("idtop10", $_GET[idtop10]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $top10 = $stmt->fetchObject();
    $dbh = null;
    echo '{"item":'. json_encode($top10) .'}';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
?>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
var serviceUrl ="..\MovieManiac1.0\assets\www\";
var top10s;

$('#top10list').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getTop10List();
});

function getTop10List() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'gettop10.php', function(data) {
    $('#top10list li').remove();
    top10s = data.items;
    $.each(top10s, function(index, top10) {
        $('#top10list').append('<li><a href="top10.php?id=' + top10.idmovie + '">' + '<h4>' + movie.moviename + '</h4>' + '<p>' + movie.moviename + '</p>' + '<p>' + movie.description + '</p>'+ '</a></li>'); 
    $('#top10list').listview('refresh');
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: So are there any errors displayed from php or you just cant show data in android ? I see this line var serviceUrl ="..\MovieManiac1.0\assets\www\"; You are trying to get db results from php file that is on android phone ? I don't think so

Comment: i used eclipse to build my android project. so i putted my php, javascript and html files at www folder. i did'nt get error displayed from php and data can't showed. i've tested on android virtual device and browser, it didn't come up too.

Comment: if your php file doesent output results you are doing something wrong. Turn on error reporting and first debug php file. Also I don't think you will be able to connect to remote database from your android device, try it and if it is so you need to call remote php script that will return json response and then use it in your app